# Cannot create property 'mirror' on string 'true' in Kendo Chart

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, linechart, kendo-chart

I am using Kendo chart in my project.
This is my kendo chart html file.

```
<kendo-chart>
   <kendo-chart-tooltip [shared]="true"></kendo-chart-tooltip>
   <kendo-chart-legend position="bottom"></kendo-chart-legend>
   <kendo-chart-category-axis>
   <kendo-chart-category-axis-item labels="true" [line]="{visible:true}" mirror="true"
                    [categories]="categories">
   </kendo-chart-category-axis-item>
   </kendo-chart-category-axis>
           
   <kendo-chart-area background="#00000000"></kendo-chart-area>
          <kendo-chart-series>
                <kendo-chart-series-item *ngFor="let item of kapanAnaItem.planProdSeries" [data]="item.data" type="bar"
                    [name]="item.name" [color]="item.color">
                </kendo-chart-series-item>
            </kendo-chart-series>
        </kendo-chart>
```

Below image is my data coming from server.

[image]

But when this data is bind then it will give me below error.

[image]

I do lots of research but nothing can help me to solve this issue.

Any Help will be Appreciated...

Comment: I don't see any API regarding the `mirror` input in the mentioned component. https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/CategoryAxisItemComponent/ Have you tried `[mirror]="true"`?

Comment: @YongShun yes I tried but it give me same error. and one thing is there if the data is positive decimal then it will work fine. It only give error on negative values.

Answer (score 0):

In the following row, the syntax `labels="true"` actually passes the string `"true"` into the input `labels`.

```
<kendo-chart-category-axis-item labels="true" [line]="{visible:true}" mirror="true"
```

To pass the boolean value `true`, you need to use the following syntax: `[labels]="true"`.

In any case, the `labels` input shouldn't receive a boolean value, it should receive an object of type `CategoryAxisLabels`, which among other properties, contains a property named `mirror`.

So the problem is that you're passing the string "true" into an input that expects an object and when the component tries to access the object's  `mirror` member, you get the error `"Cannot create property 'mirror' on string 'true'"`.

You can see a full list of the members of the `CategoryAxisLabels` type in the [official documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/charts/api/CategoryAxisLabels/).

By the way, `CategoryAxisItemComponent` doesn't have an input named `mirror`. Like I pointed out earlier, it's a member of the `CategoryAxisLabels` object, so you can remove it from `kendo-chart-category-axis-item`.